# How to work out the gravitational potential energy of rotating rod

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, rotational-kinematics

I know that the kinetic energy of a rotating rod is 
$$
KE_{rot}=\frac12I\omega^2
$$
 where $I$ is the moment of inertia. But is there some way to calculate gravitational potential energy using just mass, length and angle and not involving torque?

Answer (score 5):

When calculating gravitational potential energy the only thing that matters is the position of the centre of gravity. So if the vertical position of the centre of gravity changes by $\Delta h$ the gravitational potential energy changes by $\Delta V = mg\Delta h$.